# DNS does not work on Amazon EC2 running Windows Server 2008R2 and Parallels plesk panel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, plesk

I have created an Instance in Amazon EC2 running windows 2008 R2 and Parallels plesk power panel. My domain is with Godaddy and I need to point that domain to my EC2 instance. I have associated an EIP to that instance.

To setup DNS I use Parallels plesk panel instead of Route 53. I have created NS ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com and appropriate A records. Following are the settings

[image]

I also checked the name servers on whatsmydns.net for propagation status. It has been 12 hours but not even 1 location showed up green.

Important: As I'm using static IP there is no IPV4 configured in the local network. IP address are set to assign automatically. When I tried to install DNS Service from IIS it showed a pop saying. No static IP address was found on this computer. How do I set up a proper DNS in this case?

Comment: On which NS servers your domain delegated?(NS servers used in your domain's registrar panel for your domain name)